# Twitter Verified followers list

Tags: python, twitter

Is there a way to pull only "verified list of followers" of some public twitter account who has got millions of followers using python or any other software

Answer (score 0):

So you can view all verified twitter users by the list of accounts being followed by [twitter.com/verified](https://twitter.com/verified)

If you have twitter API tokens (which aren't entirely trivial to get but can be done for free) you can [clone this git repo](https://github.com/thansen0/verified_twitters) and generate the list on your own.

If you're ok with an out of date list, one is provided in the [repo above as well](https://github.com/thansen0/verified_twitters) in csv format. Obviously you've probably moved on from this project but I just wanted to comment for anyone else who comes across this post looking for an answer.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you could use selenium to do so.

https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/

Comment: Thank you for your response. Is there a code which I can use?